# Golang Interface with functions receiving specified Interface args

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to use interfaces in Go to achive two advantages:

1. Protect myself of mixing up variables order
2. Make package independent from each other, so one day I'll can easily replace one of them.

In my particular case I can find workaroung, but I can't understand why the way I try cannot work, it seems simple and logically.

Here is what I do.

In one package (named handlers) I have an interface describing a function I need, just something receiving `Account`.

```golang
package handlers

type Accounter interface {
    AddAccount(a Account)
}

type Account interface {
    AccountID() int64
    UserID() int64
    OtherID() int64

}
```

In other package of my programm (named accounter) I have function matching the interface, and definition of `Account` interface to avoid importing this interface from first package.

```golang
package accounter

type Account interface {
    AccountID() int64
    UserID() int64
    OtherID() int64
}

func (x *accounter) AddAccount(a Account) {
...
}
```

But the `go vet` tells me that I can't do such thing:

```
configure_stats_loader.go:109:64: cannot use x (type *accounter.Accounter) as type handlers.Accounter in argument to handlers.AddAccHandler:
    *accounter.Accounter does not implement handlers.Accounter (wrong type for AddAccount method)
        have AddAccount(accounter.Account)
        want AddAccount(handlers.Account)
```

In this case I have to solutions:

1. Import `Account` interface from one of the packages.
2. Define function receving values in standard go types like `(UserID, AccoutID, OtherID int64)`.

In first case I loose indepence in packages and in some future I'll cannot replace `Accounter` interface without rewriting some code (not a lot of code, but still), in second case, if I'll have a lot of similar methods and a lot of parameters in `Account`, I can accidentaly  mix up order of variables. For example accidentaly use `AccountID` as `UserID`.

And now the question: Is there some way to have all advantages? Get protection from mixing up variables order and avoid imports from one package to another.

Comment: These are two separate interfaces in separates packages, they are not the same. Define the interface in a single package and reuse it from the other. If you want to separate those two packages, use a third package that only contains interfaces.

Comment: @Marc Thank you.
Well, the third package seems a little cumbersome, but it's a solution.

Comment: And don't solve problems you might only have "one day". Unless you're designing an API, you can always move/replace packages later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing @Marc comments, a "third-party" package is perfect for defining common types. This is common practice especially when dealing with [gRPC generated code](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/).

Also as per [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) keep interfaces short:

> Interfaces with only one or two methods are common in Go code

So avoid laborious getter/setter definitions - and focus on larger operations. So I'd suggest in your "types" package:

```
package mydefs

// concrete type: used for Creation and lookup
type Account struct {
    ID      int64
    UserID  int64
    OtherID int64
}

// abstract interface: keep method list short
type Accounter interface {
    Add(a Account) error             //
    Get(a Account) (Account, error)  // use concrete type as a lookup request type
}
```